# CI Static D/C/M Routes and URI params

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have a bit of a tricky one, and I'm not even sure if CI is designed to work this way.

I have a subdomain, lets call it test.warren.com

test.warren.com points to a CI index.php, which is separate from the main index.php that is loaded when accessing warren.com.

The test.warren.com's index.php has static routes defined, as per the CI comments

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    $routing['directory']   = 'subdir';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    $routing['controller']  = 'testcontroller';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    $routing['function']    = 'testmethod';
```

Now this all works dandy - I have my one-method website. Nothing else is accessible; only that method. If I go to test.warren.com - I get whatever is executed by testmethod().

Now, the part I can't do - is pass in URI params
EG: test.warren.com/param1/param2/param3  --- 404

As far as I can debug the reason this doesn't work is because when the router class is initialized, it tries to check if 'param1' is a controller class or a directory; which is in-line with what a standard CI configuration would expect. And then 404s out.

I think I can work around it by editing the main core/CodeIgniter.php that is loaded at the bottom of index.php; but I'm very hesitant as this CI installation has multiple site installations.

CI is v2.0.3

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: are you trying to directly pass the parameter right after your domain name as you mentioned in your example test.warren.com/param1/param2/param3?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your "default route" in this way, you will need to setup a secondary route to pass the paramaters.

i.e.

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/action/$1/$2/$3';
```

This "should" work, as to match it, you would have to pass three parameters and if you don't pass three, it will revert to the default controller or 404 (if only one or two are passed.)

Hope that helps?